# How to sort Integers without making them an Array or List in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Let's say I have an  array of Employee objects.

A single employee object has parameters such as : **name, age and department.**

I need to sort the Employee objects by their age.

I know how to do this except for one part.

When I use the compareTo method, I need to specify how to sort the integers.

How would I do this with making them an array of integers or list?

**EDIT**

Here is my code to further clarify what I need to do.

```
public class Company {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Employee[] e = new Employee[13];
        PrimeAgeChecker p = new PrimeAgeChecker();
        Department d = new Department();
        e[0] = new Employee("Counting Guru",55,"Accounting");
        e[1] = new Employee("Counting Pro",45,"Accounting");
        e[2] = new Employee("Counting Savvy",40,"Accounting");
        e[3] = new Employee("Counting Novice",25,"Accounting");
        e[4] = new Employee("Sales Guru",50,"Marketing");
        e[5] = new Employee("Sales Pro",48,"Marketing");
        e[6] = new Employee("Sales Savvy",38,"Marketing");
        e[7] = new Employee("Hiring Guru",58,"Human Resrouces");
        e[8] = new Employee("Hiring Pro",47,"Human Resrouces");
        e[9] = new Employee("Hacking Pro",47,"Information Systems");
        e[10] = new Employee("Hacking Guru",51,"Information Systems");
        e[11] = new Employee("Hacking Savvy",38,"Information Systems");
        e[12] = new Employee("Hacking Novice",23,"Information Systems");


        for(int i = 0;i<e.length;i++){
            System.out.println(e[i] + " " + p.isPrime(e[i]));
        }//end 
    }//end main
}//end company
```

As you can see, each Employee object takes 3 parameters.

I need to sort them by the integer which is their age.

Comment: No array, No list? . Then how are you storing them??

Comment: I think he just means without putting all the ints in an array as he already has the employees in an array

Comment: It's not possible without some form of data structure to hold the sorted order objects.

Comment: I edited the post to further clarify what I need to do.

Comment: "When I use the compareTo method, I need to specify how to sort the integers." - I am afraid I don't quite understand this statement

Comment: @MrTimotheos You can simply access the age by e[0].age or e[1].age....so on that basis you can have your sort function.

Answer (score 8):

You should have a look at the [`sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29) method of the `Arrays` class

`public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`

You will need to create a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to tell it how to order your employees

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Similarly, if you had a `List` or other type of `Collection` you could use the `sort` method of [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: +1 An alternative to creating a `Comparator` is to have `Employee` implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), comparing ages.

Comment: @JasonC I'd say that's a bad habit, though; only inherent natural orders should be implemented directly on the class.

Comment: @chrylis - That is true.  On that happy note, I have deleted my answer, in which I did exactly that.